# Crawler ignoring Custom User Property

Tags: 2013, user-profile, crawled-property

Ultimatevely, I want filter results from SharePoint search using data from BCS.

I created custom user property and map it to the BCS. Everything works fins (I can see data for each user in this field).
However, crawler is just not picking this property (missing both in Crawled properties).

At this point, I manually added both Crawled and Managed Properties with PowerShell with following script

```
$searchapp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "Search Service Application" 
$category = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCategory –Identity People -SearchApplication $searchapp
$crawledproperty = New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -SearchApplication $searchapp -Category $category -VariantType 31 -PropSet "00110329-0000-0110-c000-000000111146" -Name People:ext_Searchable -IsNameEnum $false 
$managedproperty = New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $searchapp -Name ext_Searchable -Type 1
New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping -SearchApplication $searchapp -ManagedProperty $managedproperty -CrawledProperty $crawledproperty
```

After executing script and doing Full Crawl, I can see properties in Search Schema, however, when they are still missing from Query Builder (Result Sources in Search Application -> Local People Results -> Copy -> Launch Query Builder).

Answer (score 0):

BCS and User Profile Properties can only be mapped in the Search Service Application (SSA) so I would begin by removing any manually created fields from the site or site collection and look in the SSA Search Schema.

Look under the People category in Crawled Properties. You should not have to create the crawled property either, I would remove that. Ensure that you have at least one profile with the column populated and perform a full crawl of the profiles.

Once you can see the crawled property you can create the related Managed Property. To use it in Query Builder it needs to be marked Queryable.

Comment: The problem is - I can't see my custom property in Crawled Properties. Yes, there is at least one profile with data in this property and yes this property is marked as "Indexed" and, by now, several full crawl were preformed (scope - sps3://<mysitehost>)

Comment: What is showing in the crawl logs for that content source? Are you getting any errors? You have to resolve that problem before moving forward.

Comment: There are no errors, no warnings, no top level errors and no deletes (everything is under "Successes"). Also, both UVLS and Event Viewers are clear. I'm thinking problem is in crawler scope, but I'm not sure which URL should I pass him - every URL which is remotely close to user profile is added to his scope (with sps3 protocol, instead http) - so far no luck

Comment: Time to call Microsoft or get a consultant to assist in troubleshooting.